# change the background color of layout which have fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragment in my code so i cant change the background color of whole activity please help me.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/exercisetype_list"
     android:name="de.skubware.opentraining.activity.create_workout.ExerciseTypeListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
tools:context=".ExerciseTypeListActivity"
tools:layout="@layout/list_content" 
/>
```

following is the activity which we used for the fragments and already set the background list_content but still not change the background color of whole layout with fragment
list_content activity

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#000000" >
    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Loading"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
             android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android.R.internalEmpty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please attach some screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background of layout -> list_Contnet as this is the layout consuming all the space.

Comment: Yes i have set the layout->list_content.

Comment: your question statement is very unclear. set background should work until unless you have not overridden it. If nothing works check it out getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(int color)